# Why do I see more processes in KVM than in OpenVZ?

Tags: linux, process, kvm, openvz

I've got a 512mb Centos 6 VPS running on KVM.
Now another VPS from a org. I manage is running on OVZ.

When I type top on the KVM one, I get a whole list of all sort off processes.
But when I do this in the OVZ one, I only get around 20, which is normal.

So how do I close all those (unneccesary?) processes and keep it clean?
Here is a screen of what top looks like now:

[image: top]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are mostly normal processes that you have to incur when running a Linux distribution on bare metal or as a virtual machine on other technologies such as KVM or VirtualBox. The difference you're seeing can be directly attributed to the virtualization technology differences.

Technologies such as KVM & VirtualBox, virtualize at the hardware level, esentially providing virtual versions of the hardware to the guest OSes. Technologies such as OpenVZ virtualize at the process level, therefore each guest VM has their own `init` process, but they all share the same Linux Kernel. This is why when you use OpenVZ all the guest OSes have to be the same distribution as the host OS.

The advantage of using OpenVZ as you can attest to, is the much smaller footprints that the guest OSes have to consume, thereby leaving more of a system's resources available, to be devoted to the VMs.

The primary drawbacks to using OpenVZ is that all the guests have to use  the same Kernel, and a special Linux Kernel needs to be maintained with the OpenVZ technologies included.

#### So there is nothing to remove then?

One thing you can do to trim your CentOS footprint would be to disable any services that you know you don't need. Disabling services is often the best method for trimming down a system both in the resources it needs to consume as well as in hardening it from a security perspective.

#### Example

Here's a system that I recently setup (CentOS 6.5) for use as a web proxy. I run the system in runlevel 3 since it has no GUI and is basically just a server.

```
$ sudo chkconfig --list | grep 3:on
NetworkManager  0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
acpid           0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
auditd          0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
blk-availability    0:off   1:on    2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
cpuspeed        0:off   1:on    2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
crond           0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
haldaemon       0:off   1:off   2:off   3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
irqbalance      0:off   1:off   2:off   3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
livesys         0:off   1:off   2:off   3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
livesys-late    0:off   1:off   2:off   3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
lvm2-monitor    0:off   1:on    2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
messagebus      0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
netfs           0:off   1:off   2:off   3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
nginx           0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
ntpd            0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
postfix         0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
rsyslog         0:off   1:off   2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
sshd            0:off   1:off   2:off   3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
sysstat         0:off   1:on    2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
udev-post       0:off   1:on    2:on    3:on    4:on    5:on    6:off
```

If you have any services that you know you don't need then I encourage you to disable them like so. This is a 2 step process. The first step will stop the service. The second step will disable that service from starting up again during reboots.

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/nginx stop
$ sudo chkconfig nginx off
```

Use the same method above to disable other services, simply change the name from `nginx` to `serviceX`.

Comment: Nice answer, but although you need to run Linux guests with openzv, the do not all need to be the same OS. I typically run either Centos or Debian as openVZ guests. A very simple solution if you are running openvz is to use Proxmox (Debian host + KVM + openvz + web interface for guest management).

Comment: @bodhi.zazen - They all use the same kernel though, no? I use OpenVZ on CentOS 5.x and thought they were all using the same Kernel.

Comment: Yes, the guests all use the same kernel, and if you define an OS as the kernel, then yes they all use the same OS. OS is non-specific though as many people include more then the kernel (Linux vs GNU/Linux I suppose). The administration, repositories, and packages will vary with the guest. I host a few "open source projects" using openvz and people almost never ask me what kernel the want to run, the want to run a Debian/Centos guest depending on their sys admin preferences/experience.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen - wasn't my intention to imply OS == Kernel, I'll clean up the text. Fixed!

Comment: @bodhi.zazen - yeah most ppl are oblivious to Kernel version. I too run my entire infrastructure on OpenVZ so it's actually awesome from the perspective of giving you containers to keep server stacks w/in. But still realize the most use of your resources over KVM etc.

Comment: cheers, always nice to find another fan of openvz, wish the openvz patch was accepted into the mainline kernel.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen - agreed. Would make using it brain dead simple. I think the implementation must be messy. Also I think Linux Containers is a better implementation, hence why OpenVZ hasn't. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Linux_Containers. This is a similar scenario to Xen vs. KVM.

Comment: LXC is going to be nice once it matures a bit. Development is a bit too rapid for my tastes on a "production" server. Proxmox plans to add LXC , but I am not user of the progress.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen - agreed. Give it another 1-2 years is where I'm at with it.

Answer (score 3):

Most of those processes -- the ones at the bottom with all zero stats -- are kernel threads.  You won't see them under OpenVZ because the containment is different.

That leaves you with 17 actual user space processes.  Of those, the only ones that might be considered unnecessary on a VPS are the `mingetty`'s, but:

- Getting rid of those would require reconfiguration of the init daemon.
- They are tiny and inactive and not worth worrying about.  If the VPS provider has the system set up this way, just leave it.